# Sonarqube path locations and wildcards

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to configure Sonarqube to run an analysis through TeamCity with multiple projects in a solution with a structure like this:

```
Projectname.Core
Projectname.Database
Projectname.Services
Projectname.Test.Common
Projectname.Tests.Database
Projectname.WebApi
Projectname.WebUI
```

Now, as you can see, i'd effectively like the "sources location" to be something like

```
Projectname.*
```

and the tests location to be something like

```
Projectname.Test*\bin\release
```

and the binaries location to be something like

```
Projectname.*\bin
```

When I try to do this in the Sonarqube runner in TeamCity, it thinks `*` is an invalid character and fails the build.

The information i've found online seems to suggest that `*` and `**` are accepted characters as per [This document](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns)

Has anyone had experience with including multiple projects to be analyzed, and if so, how do you include them all with some kind of syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns you cite aren't *invalid*; they're simply unrecognized. I.E. they're not expected in this context. What you want is a multi-module project structure. If you're using Maven (and presumably Gradle) this just works automatically. Outside of that, you'll need to [set it up explicitly](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages).

Comment: Thanks very much! looks like when you're using the teamcity plugin, the way to go is to add a properties file to each project in any case. Will take this forward.